# Setting Jpeg as background in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Can we set a jpeg image as a live wallpaper?

if yes then how? please share some links or code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read and draw the jpeg on a canvas. Here is a link to an existing post on stackoverflow. [Live Wallpaper Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302709/live-wallpaper-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you just have to [decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) the [bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) and then draw it on screen.

```
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResoource(getResources(), R.drawable.jpegimage);
canvas.drawBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, null);
```

theres alot of examples covering how to draw on screen just Google it up